# How can I prevent finding executable on $PATH?

Tags: linux, path

I am using a system with an incomplete installation of GNAT, the GNU Ada compiler.  A script (in the gdb testsuite) is finding `/usr/bin/gnatmake` and assumes that it can run Ada compiles.  These fail because a the linker can't find `libgnat.so`.

I don't have root access, so I can't install `libgnat.so` or remove `/usr/bin/gnatmake`.

Is there any way to prevent a script from finding gnatmake in `/usr/bin`?  I clearly cannot remove `/usr/bin` from the path.

Comment: Can't you configure your script invocation, or change it, so that your `/usr/bin/gnatmake` is ignored? Or can't you put `/usr/bin` quite deep in your path?

Comment: Without root access, there's likely nothing you can do about it unless the script can be configured to explicitly ignore it. Even with it deep in the PATH, the script would still find it if it's in the path at all...

Comment: @NiklasB. in Ada Compiler there is option

Comment: @Sam: As non-root, you shouldn't be able to `chmod` anything in `/usr/bin`, I hope. OP says he hasn't access to the GNAT installation.

Answer (score 2):

Can you install a private, working version of `gnatmake`?

If you can, then you can create a symlink to the working version of `gnatmake` in your `$HOME/bin` directory:

```
ln -s /path/to/real/gnatmake ~/bin/gnatmake
```

Then insert your own `$HOME/bin` directory into your `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Now the shell will find your version of `gnatmake` before the one in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo`ing the script as yourself (`sudo -u you ./script`). In case you're not allow to `sudo`, you can also try `exec VAR=val ./script`. A third way would be to add another directory to `$PATH` with 'fake' empty scripts to shadow the ADA files.